# Is there an available list for DISTRO_FEATURES_append?

Tags: yocto, openembedded

Is there an available list for DISTRO_FEATURES_append?

for example:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
```

This is the only one I have known but I want to know is any else I can choose.

Another question, can we add *.bb directly into DISTRO_FEATURES_append?

ex:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " dmidecode"
```

Comment: I do not understand your second question. `DISTRO_FEATURES` and a recipe are two different things. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bitbake IMAGE_NAME -e | grep DISTRO_FEATURES=
```